# 401 unathorised when using windows authentication to access web services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis-7, http-status-code-401

I have a asp.net mvc 4.0 web application that attempts to use windows authentication to authenticate against some web services. its hosted in iis7

The web services are autodesk vault 2011 web services, I present the user with a login screen where they can use a vault user account or they can use their windows login. There is no issue with using a vault account it logs in via the vault web services and call the various vault web services such as pulling data out of the vault. no issues here

When trying to log in using windows authentication then I get a 401 error when accessing the web services

I think that it could be a double hop issue so the server admins are going to enable Kerberos so we can at least eliminate this as a possibility. In the live environment the site and web services are located on different servers.

However for testing I have a virtual machine setup and the site and web services are on the same machine and I still get a 401 issue so maybe it is an iis configuration issue and not a double hop issue as originally thought

I have tried the following but with no success

I have added the following code to the winauthservice (I have wrapped the web services so that I can override the invoke and I have created a factory class to instantiate the services)

```
this.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;

var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();

credentialCache.Add(new Uri(this.Url), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(identity.Name, identity.Password.ConvertToUNSecureString(), identity.Name.Substring(0, identity.Name.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))));

this.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

I have also tried it with Negotiate instead of NTLM

I have disabled the loopback check in the registry and I have added the server name and localhost to the BackConnectionHostNames registry entry

I have disabled anonymous authentication for the web site in iis and enabled windows authentication. In the providers for windows authentication I have removed negotiate and just left NTLM as saw a post recommending to do this.

In the web.config I have set authentication `mode = windows`

I have the following in my IIS logs

> 2013-09-25 09:11:05 fe80::9565:6102:fe2d:8f41%10 POST /AutodeskDM/Services/WinAuth/WinAuthService.asmx - 80 - fe80::9565:6102:fe2d:8f41%10 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.296) 401 2 5 11572
>   2013-09-25 09:11:05 fe80::9565:6102:fe2d:8f41%10 POST /AutodeskDM/Services/WinAuth/WinAuthService.asmx - 80 - fe80::9565:6102:fe2d:8f41%10 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.296) 401 1 3221225581 10

I'm running out of ideas as to what the issue could now be, but my thought is if I can get this working in my test vm then I may have more luck in the live environment

Comment: hmmm, just changed it so that UseDefaultCredentials = true; and now I'm logging in fine using windows authentication. Pretty sure this didn't work yesterday, however I have to enable basic authentication otherwise it doesn't use the correct user details in the windows authentication, I know this because I have two accounts set up one is an administrator and one just has basic permissions but it gains administrator rights

Comment: I think this may be a double hop issue after all, however not sure how I can test this in my VM as they are on the same IIS. However, any ideas why I can't specify the user in the credential cache using NTLM or negotiate as this still causes a 401 error, if I could fix this then I would hope that this would fix the issue on the live servers in case the kerberos isn't set correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with authentication surviving a redirect when using a `HttpWebRequest` object, but I'm not sure if this is your problem. I noticed the redirect and the missing authentication using [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/).

What I had to do was to set `PreAuthenticate = true` on the `HttpWebRequest` object

```
HttpWebRequest request;
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = new CredentialCache {{uri, "Basic", credentials}};
```

But, like I said, I'm not sure if this applies in your situation though.

Comment: yeah tried that as well and it's not made any difference, fiddler informs me of a 401.2 so going to see if I can make any head way on that. I'm back on site tomorrow so hopefully UseDefaultCredentials and kerberos enabled sorts it. If I can get this credentialcache to work then at least I have another option to work with. Not holding out much hope though :( Thanks for the reply though much appreciated